# Maven central - cannot find wagon plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, wagon

I'm having problems trying to find and get the maven wagon plugin.

In my pom.xml I have the following:

...

```
 <!-- Repositories -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>mavencentral</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

and

```
<pluginRepositories>
         <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
          <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>

    </pluginRepositories>
```

Yet when I run mvn install I get the following:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project app.ui: Could not resolve dependencies for project my.project:war:1.9.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon:jar:2.8 in central (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

What am I missing? What do I need to do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `s` of `https` in the URL. Also, you do not need to specify this and you can delete that part of your pom.xml. Maven, by default, will look at `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2` to fetch dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @Tunaki, yes I tried this. However it still did not fix it.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? If so, it needs to be configured in `settings.xml`.

Comment: No, am not behind a proxy.

Comment: The artifact org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon:jar:2.8 does not exist where it's been looked for. Look in the directory http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon/2.8/ there is no jar, only a pom. Is this a dependency from you project or from a plugin?

Comment: Hi @StephaneM, I am trying to add this as a plugin, so that I can copy the artifact to the server upon successful build.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve *this* issue

```
<build>
<extensions>
    <extension>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
       <artifactId>wagon-ssh</artifactId>
       <version>${maven.wagon.version}</version>
 </extension>
</extensions>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
               <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>${maven.wagon.version}</version>
                   <configuration>
                    <serverId>appui</serverId>
                    <fromFile>${project.build.directory}</fromFile>
                    <includes>${project.build.finalName}.war</includes>
                    <url>scp://localhost:2221/</url>                     
                    <toDir>/opt/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments</toDir>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                 <execution>

                   <id>upload-war-to-server</id>
                   <phase>upload</phase>
                   <goals>
                     <goal>upload-single</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                        <serverId>appui</serverId>
                        <fromFile>${project.build.directory}</fromFile>
                        <includes>${project.build.finalName}.war</includes>
                        <url>scp://localhost:2221/opt/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments</url>            

                    </configuration>
                 </execution>
               </executions>
        </plugin>
```